Appwrite build error : Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-bom:4.10.0
Appwrite docs: https://appwrite.io/docs/quick-starts/android
Error reference : https://github.com/appwrite/sdk-for-android/issues/42
build.gradle (app)
dependencies {

    // other dependencies

 
 implementation(platform("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-bom:4.12.0"))
 implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp")

implementation("io.appwrite:sdk-for-android:4.0.1")

}

Error while building:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:devDebugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-bom:4.10.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > io.appwrite:sdk-for-android:4.0.1
      > No matching variant of com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-bom:4.12.0 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during compile-time, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.ProductFlavor:environment' with value 'dev', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.2.2', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-bom:4.12.0 declares a component for use during compile-time:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a platform and the consumer needed a library

